# Why does my MLKit model always returns an error when processing an image?

Tags: ios, google-mlkit

I have a Google MLKit model for labeling an Image after capturing the image, but everytime I tried to process the Image, it always give me this error:

> label process error:: Pipeline failed to fully start: Calculator::Open() for node "ClassifierClientCalculator" failed: #vk The TFLite Model Metadata must not contain label maps when `text_label_map_file` is used.

Here's my MLKit image labeler configuration code (this code is based on MLKit's documentation):

```
private func configureModelSource() { // Called in viewDidLoad()
    guard let manifestPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "filename", ofType: "json") else { return }
    guard let localModel = LocalModel(manifestPath: manifestPath) else { return }
    let options = CustomImageLabelerOptions(localModel: localModel)
    options.confidenceThreshold = NSNumber(value: 0.0)
    imageLabeler = ImageLabeler.imageLabeler(options: options)
}

private func processImage(with image: UIImage) { // Called after capturing an Image
    guard imageLabeler != nil else { return }
    
    let visionImage = VisionImage(image: image)
    visionImage.orientation = image.imageOrientation
    
    imageLabeler?.process(visionImage) { labels, error in
        guard error == nil, let labels = labels, !labels.isEmpty else {
            print("label process error:: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "nil")")
            return
        }
        for label in labels {
            // Do something...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to solve this? For context, the `model.tflite` file was updated. The file before the one that gives me this error works as expected. But the new `model.tflite` file always gives me this error everytime I run my app. Is this a file-related error or did I do something wrong with my code that I have to also update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my understanding based on the error message:

Given you are using the `LocalModel(manifestPath: manifestPath)` API, it is expecting a legacy TFLite model format where the label map is provided through a separate text file and the `model.tflite` itself does not contain the label map. That's why your file before your model update works.

To use your updated `model.tflite` (which seems to contain the lab map inside its metadata), I think you can try the following to use the `model.tflite` file directly with the custom models API without going through the `filename.json` manifest:

```
guard let modelPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "model", ofType: "tflite") else { return }
guard let localModel = LocalModel(path: modelPath) else { return }
```

You can check out the documentation about custom models here: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/image-labeling/custom-models/ios